# Importing Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl

How can i import a perl project into eclipse workspace using commandline? I am using EPIC plugin along with padwalker for debugging

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using the following command (I'm using Eclipse Galileo in Mac OSX):

```
 /Users/me/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -nosplash \
    -data /path/to/workspace \
    -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild \
    -import /path/to/your/project
```

It requires 2 things:

- Install Eclipse CDT (C/C++ Development Tools)
- Create a `.project` file in your project folder prior to importing it

Here's an example EPIC `.project` file, change `my_project_name` so it matches your project's own:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my_project_name</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.epic.perleditor.perlbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.epic.perleditor.perlnature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. 1. Where can I get the value of -application? 2. Is the parameter -application mandatory?

Comment: 1. that's something you get automatically when you install CDT; 2. AFAIK, yes, although there may be alternatives, such as org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild -haven't tested it though

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above commands works partially. 1. I call the eclipse in commandline with 3 parameters -data, -application & -import -> This open an empty eclipse project 2. Then I call the eclipse in commandline with 2 parameters -data & -import -> Now I am able to import the required project Any other commands that would allow import of project in a single command/session?

Comment: Dunno. It works for me with only a single run of the command. I'm using Galileo, btw.